# How to empty input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, numbers, field

I am in a mobile app and I use an input field in order user submit a number.

When I go back and return to the page that input field present the latest number input displayed at the input field.

Is there any way to clear the field every time the page load?

```
$('#shares').keyup(function(){
    payment = 0;
    calcTotal();
    gtotal = ($('#shares').val() * 1) + payment;
    gtotal = gtotal.toFixed(2);
    $("p.total").html("Total Payment: <strong>" + gtotal + "</strong>");
});
```

Answer (score 498, accepted):

You can clear the input field by using `$('#shares').val('');`

Comment: Does this work and is is it specification compliant if we have a numeric input like so `<input type="number" min="0' max="10" value="5"></input>`? I guess said differently, are you allowed to set a numeric input to be blank?

Comment: How about `.val([])`?

Comment: On a related note, `.val([])` can also unselect any selected option in select list... not so much with `.val('')`. Best thing about it is it's cross-browser support. **P.S:** This is an alternative to only other efficient cross-browser solution - `$("select option").prop("selected", false);` but works with all inputs. Thanks to [Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) for [a test he created](http://jsfiddle.net/jS3ws/).

Answer (score 36):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#shares').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 35):

To reset text, number, search, textarea inputs:

```
$('#shares').val('');
```

To reset select:

```
$('#select-box').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

To reset radio input:

```
$('#radio-input').attr('checked',false);
```

To reset file input:

```
$("#file-input").val(null);
```

Answer (score 16):

While submitting form use reset method on form. The reset() method resets the values of all elements in a form.

```
$('#form-id')[0].reset();

OR 

document.getElementById("form-id").reset();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

```js
$("#submit-button").on("click", function(){
       //code here
       $('#form-id')[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form-id">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can help someone but in this context your answer is useless.

Comment: thank bro, it helped me i was using '' but using (reset) is better!

Comment: Thank you Radhika!

Answer (score 9):

Setting `val('')` will empty the input field. So you would use this:

Clear the input field when the page loads:

```
$(function(){
    $('#shares').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using jQuery, how about using a trigger-[reset](http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#shares').trigger(':reset');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you hit the "back" button it usually tends to stick, what you can do is when the form is submitted clear the element then before it goes to the next page but after doing with the element what you need to.

```
    $('#shares').keyup(function(){
                payment = 0;
                calcTotal();
                gtotal = ($('#shares').val() * 1) + payment;
                gtotal = gtotal.toFixed(2);
                $('#shares').val('');
                $("p.total").html("Total Payment: <strong>" + gtotal + "</strong>");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is pre-filled (e.g. in a submitted search form), you have to clear the value-attribute as well:

```
$("#clearSearch").on('click', function(){
  $('#search').val('').attr('value','');
});
```