# How to limit the number of clones which can be made

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use `clone()` and `remove()` with div elements. How can I make a clone limit? For example, I can clone a maximum of 10 div elements.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $('.remove').closest('.wrapper').find('.element').not(':first').last().remove();
});
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
  $('.clone').closest('.wrapper').find('.element').first().clone().appendTo('.results');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work you can check the number of `.result .element` elements before you clone the next. If the number is at the limit, don't perform the clone action.

Note in the example below that I set the limit to 2 to make testing easier, and also I made some changes to the selectors to make them more succinct.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:not(:first):last').remove();
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});

var cloneLimit = 2;

$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
  if ($('.results .element').length <= cloneLimit) { // just to make testing easier
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:first').clone().appendTo('.results');
  }
  setCloneButtonVisibility();
});

function setCloneButtonVisibility() {
  $('.wrapper .clone').toggle($('.results .element').length < cloneLimit);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="results"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can hid e clone button when i clone maximum elements

Comment: `$('.wrapper .clone').hide()`

Comment: Thank you. one question, when in div element  i  have <input name="text" type="text" />   ,it works and clone it.  but if in field  i have same text and than make clone it clones field with text, how can it clone filed but value was cleared

Comment: Set `val('')` on the elements after you clone them

Comment: Not really as your example HTML doesn't show where the `input` elements are. It's really not complicated though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236332/jquery-how-to-empty-input-field

Comment: ex. if i have like this <div class="element"><input name="text" type="text" /></div>

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove', function() {
var numItems = $('.element').length;
alert("No of element: "+numItems);
if(numItems>=1){
  $('.remove').closest('.wrapper').find('.element').not(':first').last().remove();
  }
  else{
  alert("There should be at least one element...");
  }
});
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
var numItems = $('.element').length;
var maxNoDiv=3;//No of max dived could be added in the system
alert("No of element: "+numItems);
if((numItems+1)<=maxNoDiv){
  $('.clone').closest('.wrapper').find('.element').first().clone().appendTo('.results');
  }
  else{
  alert("u cant add more than "+maxNoDiv+" divs...");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a CSS selector that will always select the last child to clone and this last child should be within a specific range.

For this you need to adjust the structure and make the element to clone inside the `result` wrapper:

```js
$('.remove').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:not(:first-of-type):last-of-type').remove();
});
$('.clone').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.element:nth-of-type(-n+3):last-of-type').clone().appendTo('.results');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.element:nth-of-type(-n+3):last-of-type {
  background:red;
}
.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="results">
      <div class="element">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">clone</button>
    <button class="remove">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `nth-of-type(-n+3):last-of-type` will select the last child among the 3 first elements, and when we have more this selector will match 0 element and you can no more clone.