# delete field entered text after alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code that when someone on input with textn id writes english it says invalid format

```
function text(name)
{
    var name = $(name).val();
    if (name.length > 0) {
        just_persian(name);
    }
}

 function just_persian(str) {
    var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;
    if (!p.test(str)) {
        alert("not format");

    }
}
```

how i delete entered english value after get alert("not format"); alert?

Comment: duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236332/jquery-how-to-empty-input-field

Comment: @henokg not really as that wipes the entire field, not just the Latin characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (!p.test(str)) {
    alert("not format");
  
    const engCharsRegexp = /^[a-z]+$/gi;
    $(str).val(str.replace(engCharsRegexp, '')));
}
```

So you just set the value as an empty string

Comment: This wipes the entire field, not the Latin characters

Comment: Try it now I made an improvement

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you can use `replace()` along with a slightly tweaked form of your regular expression to remove any non-Persian characters. Also note that I reorganised the logic slightly to make better use of the strings and objects you have access to:

```js
$('#foo').on('input', e => text(e.target));

let is_just_persian = str => /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/.test(str);
let replace_non_persian = el => $(el).val((i, v) => v.replace(/[^\u0600-\u06FF]/gi, ''));

function text(el) {
  if (el.value) {
    if (!is_just_persian(el.value)) {
      replace_non_persian(el);
      console.log('not format');
    } 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```